# Django optimise duplicate query

Tags: python, django, orm

I'm new to Django, and the ORM is a bit hard for me,

I have a search page with a query and a few criteria filters and the get_queryset is as follows (its an app store):

```
def get_queryset(self):
        ... filter object list based on GET parameter...
        return object_list.annotate(
            rating=Avg('reviews__stars'),
            downloads=Count('order_history', distinct=True),
            flag1_rate=100*Count(
                'reviews',
                filter=Q(reviews__status=Review.FLAG1)
            ) / (Count(
                'reviews',
                filter=Q(reviews__status=Review.FLAG2)
            ) + Count(
                'reviews',
                filter=Q(reviews__status=Review.FLAG1)
            ))
        ).order_by(ordered_sort)
```

As you can see I am querying for the `Count` of `FLAG1` twice (not the real name but you get the idea, I am calculating a ratio between two flags that users give during reviews using `100*FLAG1/(FLAG1+FLAG2)`):

```
Count(
     'reviews',
     filter=Q(reviews__status=Review.FLAG1)
)
```

How can I prevent this? is there a way to store it in a variable for the annotation?

Comment: Are there other flags than only `FLAG1` and `FLAG2`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem no, can I just store the result in a variable? And should I use select_related on reviews?

Comment: no unfortunately Django's annotations are not transformed in temporary variables at the sql side if you use these in later filters, annotations, etc.

Comment: You can however divide by `Count('reviews', filter=Q(reviews__status__in=[Review.FLAG1, Review.FLAG2]))`, this will likely boost efficiency, since aggregating with a filter is done with a `CASE(WHEN ...)` statement.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem And a python variable? Something like `flag1count = object_list.reviews.filter(status=Review.FLAG1).count()` and then use that in the annotation? EDIT: Yes that makes sense also

Comment: no, since these are *not* counts that are performed in Python. It is simply used to generate a query. The aggregation happens at the database layer.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Alright, but I thought generating a query also executes it immediately, so I don't fully understand that

Comment: no, Django's querysets are lazy. But by using `.count()` you *force* evaluation, because then it is no longer a queryset, but an `int` that should be returned.

Comment: And are you allowed to use `int`s in a query expression? (for annotation)

Comment: no, but it would not even make sense. `object_list` is a `QuerySet`, so it has no `reviews` attribute. It is a *collection* of model objects, not a single one. Furthermore if that would be resolved to `5` for example, then how is that `5` supposed to be different for another model object in the annotation?